# Entity Framework throws "Transaction was deadlocked"

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, transactions, deadlock

I have a Web application which is using entity framework, which is injected by `Ninject` for each request.

I have an action which temporary inserts some data into database, performs some actions, and then it removes it.

Calling this action sequentially everything works fine.

Calling this action multiple times, i get an `Transaction (Process ID 65) was deadlocked` exception exactly on Delete function.

What can be the reason of this error? Is deleting creating an internal transaction?

If yes, is there any way of "adjusting"  the transaction in order to allow concurrent calls?

*Don't ask me why i need to add and then remove the items from database - i just need, `ProcessMenu()` function is reading data from database*

```
public void UpdateEntities()
{
    ApplicationEntitiesWrapper entities = GenerateEntities();

    // ok
    InsertEntitiesInDatabase(entities);

    // process entities, ok
    ProcessMenu(entities.Menu.Id);

    // delete entities
    DeleteEntitiesFromDatabase(entities);
}

public void InsertEntitiesInDatabase(EntitiesWrapper entities)
{
    foreach (ValidationBrokenRule validationBrokenRule in entities.ValidationBrokenRules)
    {
        _db.ValidationBrokenRules.Add(validationBrokenRule);
    }

    foreach (TreePage page in entities.TreePages)
    {
        _db.TreePages.Add(page);
    }

    _db.Menus.Add(entities.Menu);

    _db.SaveChanges();
}

public void DeleteEntitiesFromDatabase(EntitiesWrapper entities)
{
    foreach (ValidationBrokenRule validationBrokenRule in entities.ValidationBrokenRules)
    {
        _db.ValidationBrokenRules.Delete(validationBrokenRule);
    }

    foreach (TreePage page in entities.TreePages)
    {
        _db.TreePages.Delete(page);
    }

    _db.Menus.Delete(entities.Menu);

    // throws "Transaction (Process ID '') was deadlocked"
    _db.SaveChanges();
}

Database tables:

ValidationBrokenRule:
Id (uniqueidentifier, PK),
Menu_Id (uniqueidentifier, FK),
Message (nvarchar)

TreePage:
Id (uniqueidentifier, PK),
ParentTreePage_Id (uniqueidentifier, FK),
Menu_Id (uniqueindentifier, FK),
Name (nvarchar)

Menu:
Id (uniqueidentifier, PK),
Name (nvarchar)
```

Comment: Without knowing more about the db design its hard to say why you are getting deadlocks, unless you are trying to delete the same record multiple times.

Comment: I've added a simple Database tables structure that i am using, focusing on FK's mostly

Comment: I think you should wrap the calls in `UpdateEntities` in a `TransactionScope`.

Comment: @GertArnold Would this be ok? From what i've read about Transactions, they should be small, if i wrap all `UpdateEntities` in a big Transaction wouldn't this block the database until all the functions are executed?

Comment: It looks like a transactional process. I don't know the size of it but a transaction log can be "large". If you think it can't be done you should consider storing some session id (e.g. a guid) with the entities so you'll be certain you never try to delete the same records from different sessions, and you can purge the tables later in case a session was disrupted.

Comment: From MSDN for `DbSet.Find`: "If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store" I know you told use not to ask but I can't help it. Are you absolutely sure that you need to call `SaveChanges()` in the `InsertEntitiesInDatabase` method and that `ProcessMenu` cannot operate/isn't already operating purely on the entities in the context?

Comment: @Colin I can't use `DbSet.Find` because it only works with PK value, and my queries contains other columns as filters

Comment: You do not need to put data into the database then remove it in order to process the menu. See what I did there? I didn't ask the question again ;-)

Comment: @Colin Ok, even if i get rid of `ProcessMenu()`, i know the error comes from deleting entities from database, which can happen anytime. That's the problem i need to solve